# How do I get Perfmon support for my kernel?

Tags: 10.04, kernel, performance, monitoring

I would like to install perfmon for using performance monitoring events on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server machine. I have read that Ubuntu kernel 2.6 comes with perfmon support. However, as we can see below, it looks like kernel2.6.32 doesn't have perfmon support. Could someone tell me how can get perfmon support. However, I have installed PAPI library and able to run all the tests successfully.

`$ pfmon`

`host kernel does not have perfmon support`

`$ uname  -a`

`Linux ubuntu-user 2.6.32-34-server #77-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 13 20:54:38 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @fossfreedom this should be an answer

Comment: @jorge - ok... have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>have turned my comment into an answer</sub>

According to [this bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pfmon/+bug/474891) on launchpad, Debian marked this as an obsolete/deprecated capability and as such was removed from Lucid.

This [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Servers) contains suggestions for alternatives for monitoring your server.

In summary:

- Nagios2 - system and network monitoring.
- Zenoss - network monitor on Ubuntu Server
- Internet Traffic Monitoring - Monitor bandwidth usage on an Internet link.
- Logwatch - monitor your system logs and have them emailed to you